Map Markers keep moving after being saved and reopened
import sys
import os
import json

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication, QMainWindow, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsPixmapItem,
    QMessageBox, QWidget, QFileDialog, QMenu, QAction, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout,
    QPushButton, QDialog, QFormLayout, QLineEdit, QTextEdit, QDialogButtonBox, QLabel, QSizePolicy
)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QUrl, QRectF, QPoint
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import QNetworkAccessManager, QNetworkRequest
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPointF
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QUrl, QRectF, QPoint, QPointF



def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for development and PyInstaller. """
    base_path = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    full_path = os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
    print(f"Base Path: {base_path}")
    print(f"Full Path: {full_path}")
    return full_path


class Marker(QGraphicsPixmapItem):
    def __init__(self, x, y, icon_path, size, text="", image_link="", image_display_callback=None, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.icon_path = icon_path # <--- Store original icon path
        self.icon_pixmap = QPixmap(icon_path)
        if self.icon_pixmap.isNull():
            raise ValueError(f"Invalid image file: {icon_path}")

        self.icon_pixmap = self.icon_pixmap.scaled(size, size, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.SmoothTransformation)
        self.setPixmap(self.icon_pixmap)
        self.setPos(x - size / 2, y - size)

        self.setCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor)
        self.tooltip_text = text
        self.tooltip_image = image_link
        self.size = size
        self.image_display_callback = image_display_callback

        self.tooltip_label = QLabel()
        self.tooltip_label.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents)
        self.init_tooltip()

    def init_tooltip(self):
        self.tooltip_label.setWindowFlags(Qt.ToolTip | Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowTransparentForInput)
        self.tooltip_label.setStyleSheet("""
        QLabel {
            background-color: white;
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-radius: 0px;
            padding: 5px;
        }""")
        self.tooltip_label.setTextFormat(Qt.RichText)
        self.tooltip_label.setStyleSheet("background: transparent;")
        self.tooltip_label.hide()

    def update_tooltip(self):
        tooltip_content = self.tooltip_text
        if tooltip_content.strip():
            self.tooltip_label.setStyleSheet("""
            QLabel {
                background-color: white;
                border: 1px solid black;
                border-radius: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
            }""")
        else:
            self.tooltip_label.setStyleSheet("background: transparent;")
        self.tooltip_label.setText(tooltip_content)

        # Trigger external display callback for bottom-right image box
        if self.image_display_callback and self.tooltip_image:
            self.image_display_callback(self.tooltip_image)

    def show_tooltip(self):
        self.update_tooltip()
        if self.tooltip_text.strip():
            self.tooltip_label.show()

    def hide_tooltip(self):
        self.tooltip_label.hide()

class MapViewer(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.setScene(self.scene)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setScene(self.scene)
        self.map_item = None
        self.markers = []
        self.marker_size = 120
        self.custom_icon_paths = []
        self.current_hovered_marker = None
        self.highlighted_marker = None
        self.zoom_factor = 1.15
        self.min_zoom_level = 0.2
        self.max_zoom_level = 10.0
        self.current_zoom_level = 1.0
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #dcc49c; border: none;")
        # Load icons for context menu
        self.load_icons()

        # Panning-related variables
        self.is_panning = False
        self.last_mouse_pos = None

        # Bottom-right image display box
        self.image_box = QLabel()
        self.init_image_box()

    def init_image_box(self):
        self.image_box.setParent(self.viewport())
        self.image_box.setFixedSize(400, 400)
        self.image_box.setStyleSheet("""
        QLabel {
            border: .1px solid black;
            background-color: white;
        }""")
        self.image_box.setScaledContents(True)
        self.image_box.hide()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        # Ensure the image box stays in the bottom-center corner
        self.image_box.move(
            (self.viewport().width() - self.image_box.width()) // 2,
            self.viewport().height() - self.image_box.height() - 10
        )

    def load_icons(self):
        icons_dir = resource_path("Icons")
        if os.path.exists(icons_dir):
            self.custom_icon_paths = [
                os.path.join(icons_dir, name)
                for name in os.listdir(icons_dir)
                if name.endswith(('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg'))
            ]

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            item_at_click = self.itemAt(event.pos())
            if isinstance(item_at_click, Marker):
                self.edit_marker(item_at_click)
            else:
                self.is_panning = True
                self.last_mouse_pos = event.pos()
        elif event.button() == Qt.RightButton:
            item_at_click = self.itemAt(event.pos())
            if isinstance(item_at_click, Marker):
                self.remove_marker(item_at_click)
            else:
                scene_pos = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
                self.show_context_menu(event.globalPos(), scene_pos)
        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.is_panning and self.last_mouse_pos:
            delta = event.pos() - self.last_mouse_pos
            self.last_mouse_pos = event.pos()
            self.horizontalScrollBar().setValue(self.horizontalScrollBar().value() - delta.x())
            self.verticalScrollBar().setValue(self.verticalScrollBar().value() - delta.y())
        else:
            scene_pos = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
            item_under_mouse = self.scene.itemAt(scene_pos, self.transform())
            if isinstance(item_under_mouse, Marker):
                if self.current_hovered_marker != item_under_mouse:
                    self.hide_tooltip_and_image()
                    self.current_hovered_marker = item_under_mouse
                    self.display_tooltip(self.current_hovered_marker, event.pos())
            else:
                self.hide_tooltip_and_image()
        super().mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.is_panning = False
            self.last_mouse_pos = None
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        if event.angleDelta().y() > 0 and self.current_zoom_level * self.zoom_factor <= self.max_zoom_level:
            self.scale(self.zoom_factor, self.zoom_factor)
            self.current_zoom_level *= self.zoom_factor
        elif event.angleDelta().y() < 0 and self.current_zoom_level / self.zoom_factor >= self.min_zoom_level:
            self.scale(1 / self.zoom_factor, 1 / self.zoom_factor)
            self.current_zoom_level /= self.zoom_factor

    def show_context_menu(self, global_pos, scene_pos):
        menu = QMenu()
        icon_menu = QMenu("Add Marker with Icon", self)
        for icon_path in self.custom_icon_paths:
            action = QAction(os.path.basename(icon_path), self)
            action.triggered.connect(lambda _, path=icon_path: self.add_marker(scene_pos.x(), scene_pos.y(), path))
            icon_menu.addAction(action)

        menu.addMenu(icon_menu)
        menu.exec_(global_pos)

    def add_marker(self, x, y, icon_path, text="", image_link=""):
        resolved_icon_path = resource_path(icon_path)
        print(f"Adding marker with icon path: {resolved_icon_path}")
        if not os.path.exists(resolved_icon_path):
            QMessageBox.critical(self, "Error", f"Icon file not found: {resolved_icon_path}")
            return

        marker = Marker(x, y, resolved_icon_path, self.marker_size, text, image_link, self.display_image)
        self.scene.addItem(marker)
        self.markers.append(marker)

    def edit_marker(self, marker):
        marker.hide_tooltip()
        dialog = MarkerEditDialog(marker.tooltip_text, marker.tooltip_image)
        if dialog.exec_() == QDialog.Accepted:
            text, image_link = dialog.get_data()
            marker.tooltip_text = text
            marker.tooltip_image = image_link

    def remove_marker(self, marker):
        if marker in self.markers:
            self.scene.removeItem(marker)
            self.markers.remove(marker)

    def display_tooltip(self, marker, mouse_position):
        if marker:
            global_position = self.viewport().mapToGlobal(mouse_position)
            marker.tooltip_label.move(global_position + QPoint(15, 15))
            marker.show_tooltip()

    def display_image(self, image_link):
        if image_link:
            pixmap = QPixmap()
            if image_link.startswith("http://") or image_link.startswith("https://"):
                manager = QNetworkAccessManager()
                request = QNetworkRequest(QUrl(image_link))
                manager.finished.connect(lambda reply: self.handle_image_reply(reply, manager))
                manager.get(request)
            else:
                pixmap = QPixmap(image_link)
                if not pixmap.isNull():
                    self.image_box.setPixmap(pixmap)
                    self.image_box.show()
                    # Anchor to bottom-center of the viewport
                    self.image_box.move(
                        (self.viewport().width() - self.image_box.width()) // 2,
                        self.viewport().height() - self.image_box.height() - 10
                    )

    def save_markers(self, file_path="markers.json"):
        if not self.map_item:
            QMessageBox.critical(None, "Error", "No map loaded to save markers.")
            return

        map_rect = self.map_item.boundingRect()  # Cached during load_image
        markers_data = []
        for marker in self.markers:
            marker_pos = self.map_item.mapFromScene(marker.scenePos())
            markers_data.append({
                "x": (marker_pos.x() - map_rect.left()) / map_rect.width(),
                "y": (marker_pos.y() - map_rect.top()) / map_rect.height(),
                "icon_path": marker.icon_path,
                "text": marker.tooltip_text,
                "image_link": marker.tooltip_image
            })

        try:
            with open(file_path, "w") as f:
                json.dump(markers_data, f)
            print(f"Markers saved to {file_path}")
        except Exception as e:
            QMessageBox.critical(None, "Error", f"Failed to save markers: {e}")

    def load_markers(self, file_path="markers.json"):
        if not self.map_item:
            QMessageBox.critical(None, "Error", "No map loaded to place markers.")
            return

        map_rect = self.map_item.boundingRect()  # Cached during load_image
        try:
            with open(file_path, "r") as f:
                markers_data = json.load(f)

            for marker_data in markers_data:
                # Convert relative coordinates back to absolute positions
                relative_x = marker_data.get("x", 0)
                relative_y = marker_data.get("y", 0)
                x = map_rect.left() + relative_x * map_rect.width()
                y = map_rect.top() + relative_y * map_rect.height()

                scene_pos = self.map_item.mapToScene(QPointF(x, y))
                icon_path = resource_path(marker_data.get("icon_path", ""))
                self.add_marker(scene_pos.x(), scene_pos.y(), icon_path, marker_data.get("text", ""),
                                marker_data.get("image_link", ""))
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("No markers file found. Starting fresh.")
        except Exception as e:
            QMessageBox.critical(None, "Error", f"Failed to load markers: {e}")

    def hide_tooltip_and_image(self):
        if self.current_hovered_marker:
            self.current_hovered_marker.hide_tooltip()
            self.image_box.hide()
            self.current_hovered_marker = None
    def zoom_in(self):
        if self.current_zoom_level * self.zoom_factor <= self.max_zoom_level:
            self.scale(self.zoom_factor, self.zoom_factor)
            self.current_zoom_level *= self.zoom_factor

    def zoom_out(self):
        if self.current_zoom_level / self.zoom_factor >= self.min_zoom_level:
            self.scale(1 / self.zoom_factor, 1 / self.zoom_factor)
            self.current_zoom_level /= self.zoom_factor
    def handle_image_reply(self, reply, manager):
        pixmap = QPixmap()
        if reply.error() == 0:
            data = reply.readAll()
            pixmap.loadFromData(data)
            self.image_box.setPixmap(pixmap)
            self.image_box.show()
            # Anchor to bottom-center
            self.image_box.move(
                (self.viewport().width() - self.image_box.width()) // 2,
                self.viewport().height() - self.image_box.height() - 10
            )
        reply.deleteLater()
        manager.deleteLater()

    def load_image(self, image_path):
        pixmap = QPixmap(image_path)
        if pixmap.isNull():
            raise FileNotFoundError(f"Could not load map image from: {image_path}")

        # Clear existing scene and markers
        self.scene.clear()
        self.map_item = QGraphicsPixmapItem(pixmap)
        self.scene.addItem(self.map_item)

        # Set scene rect to the map image dimensions
        self.setSceneRect(QRectF(pixmap.rect()))
        self.markers.clear()

        # Center the view on the map
        self.center_on_map()

        # Apply a slight zoom-out for better view
        self.resetTransform()  # Corrected capitalization
        self.scale(0.3, 0.3)  # Adjust zoom level as needed

    def center_on_map(self):
        """Center the view on the loaded map."""
        if self.map_item:
            # Center the view on the map's bounding rect center
            self.centerOn(self.map_item.boundingRect().center())


class MarkerEditDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, text="", image_link=""):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Edit Marker")
        self.resize(400, 300)  # Adjusted dialog size for better usability
        self.text_edit = QTextEdit()
        self.text_edit.setAcceptRichText(True)
        self.text_edit.setHtml(text)
        self.image_edit = QLineEdit(image_link)

        form_layout = QFormLayout()
        form_layout.addRow("Text:", self.text_edit)
        form_layout.addRow("Image Link:", self.image_edit)

        button_box = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        button_box.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        button_box.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(form_layout)
        layout.addWidget(button_box)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def get_data(self):
        return self.text_edit.toHtml(), self.image_edit.text()

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Dead Journal")
        viewer_layout = QVBoxLayout()  # Added to integrate viewer
        viewer_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.viewer = MapViewer()
        viewer_layout.addWidget(self.viewer)

        # Add Zoom In and Zoom Out buttons
        self.zoom_in_button = QPushButton("Zoom In", self)
        self.zoom_in_button.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        self.zoom_in_button.setFixedHeight(30)
        self.zoom_in_button.setObjectName("zoomInButton")
        self.zoom_in_button.clicked.connect(self.viewer.zoom_in)

        self.zoom_out_button = QPushButton("Zoom Out", self)
        self.zoom_out_button.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        self.zoom_out_button.setFixedHeight(30)
        self.zoom_out_button.setObjectName("zoomOutButton")
        self.zoom_out_button.clicked.connect(self.viewer.zoom_out)

        # Add Save button
        self.save_button = QPushButton("Save Markers", self)
        self.save_button.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        self.save_button.setFixedHeight(30)
        self.save_button.setObjectName("saveButton")
        self.save_button.clicked.connect(self.save_markers)

        self.viewer.setParent(self)

        # Button layout
        button_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        button_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        button_layout.addWidget(self.zoom_in_button)
        button_layout.addWidget(self.zoom_out_button)
        button_layout.addWidget(self.save_button)  # Add Save button to the layout

        # Main layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.addLayout(viewer_layout)  # Added viewer to main layout
        layout.addLayout(button_layout)

        container = QWidget()
        container.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(container)
        self.open_image()  # Initial map load attempt
        self.center_window()  # Center the window on the screen

    def save_markers(self):
        """Save markers using the viewer's save function."""
        try:
            self.viewer.save_markers()
            QMessageBox.information(self, "Success", "Markers saved successfully!")
        except Exception as e:
            QMessageBox.critical(self, "Error", f"Failed to save markers: {str(e)}")

    def open_image(self):
        relative_path = "IGMAP_enhanced.webp"
        default_image_path = resource_path(relative_path)

        if os.path.exists(default_image_path):
            try:
                self.viewer.load_image(default_image_path)
                self.viewer.load_markers()  # Load saved markers
            except FileNotFoundError as e:
                QMessageBox.critical(self, "Error", f"Failed to load image: {str(e)}")
        else:
            QMessageBox.critical(self, "Error", f"Default image not found at: {default_image_path}")

    def center_window(self):
        """Center the window on the screen."""
        # Ensure the window has a fixed size before centering
        self.resize(1800, 1100)  # Set the desired size for the window

        # Get the available screen geometry
        screen = QGuiApplication.primaryScreen().availableGeometry()

        # Calculate center position
        x = (screen.width() - self.width()) // 2
        y = (screen.height() - self.height()) // 2

        # Move the window to the center
        self.move(x, y)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show() 
    sys.exit(app.exec_())```    

When running this map it saves the files to a json file, when the map opens it opens the stored marker locations in the JSON file. No matter what I do. Make the marker path relative. go off of fix x and y locations, and do various conversions to ensure that there are no location rounding errors. nothing idk what is causing the map markers once they are saved to move from their original location. They keep moving up and to the left. This makes me feel that every time the JSON file is saved there is a rounding error and then it just stacks and stacks still the markers are so far from their original location that it's pointless to use the markers. Any ideas would be super amazing.

Please reduce your code to a proper [mre] by removing aspects that are not relevant to the problem.
